# i Want to count all my repeated value in mysql but i get this

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to count the number of books people take from library i am working in laravel 5 with mysql and here is the code for counting book number

```
$books= DB::table('libraries')->where('userid', '=', $request->input('userid'))
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                     ->groupBy('userid')->get();
```

i am getting this result

```
[{"number":24}]
```

but i only need the number which 24?

i tried to get it by using associated array but wont work
`$books['number']` how can i get the number and is it array

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS myCount WHERE number = '24';`

Comment: or perhaps you mean you dont understand the response format, it is JSON, you need to parse the JSON

Comment: That result is an object (json) in an array. if you do this $books = json_decode($books); How does `$books[0]->number` work for you?

Comment: $books[0]->number worked thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel doesn't return an associative array, it returns an array of objects instead (`json_decode` is not needed)

So you should be able to access your value `$books[0]->number` as mentioned by others.

But the main problem is your query. Because the user id is in your where clause, it is redundant to group by user id, which means you can eliminate the group by and simply use laravel's `count` function to get the # of rows that have a specific user id:

```
$count = DB::table('libraries')->where('userid', '=', $request->input('userid'))->count();
```

Comment: Good deal, I don't know Laravel, deleted my answer